# Time Series Stationarity

Tags: time-series, stationarity, trend, unit-root, augmented-dickey-fuller

I am confused of why my Dickey-Fuller test is significant (which implies stationarity), while the time series clearly exhibits a deterministic trend?

[image]

Comment: A deterministic trend does not seem that clear to me. A  linear trend --which is the kind of trend considered in the regression model of the Dickey-Fuller test-- is not observed as an overall long-term pattern. The [local-level model](http://personal.vu.nl/s.j.koopman/documents/LLIntro2011.pdf) can be helpful to analyse your data. For software implementing this model you may 
see [these papers](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v41). For an illustration you may also see for example [this application](http://www.jalobe.com:8080/blog/temperature-trends-in-alaska/) to temperature trends.

Answer (score 6):

Since you have put the tag "augmented-dickey-fuller", I will assume you did the ADF test with a trend.

So in that case,  if you think your series do have a *deterministic trend*, then the result of the test is indeed correct, because it is [trend stationary.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trend_stationary) That is, once you account for the deterministic trend (as you do in the ADF test), the process is stationary.